# Nested forms/models: return only records belonging to current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a music reviews site and there are 3 admins. Whenever we go to edit an album, it pulls in the nested forms for `reviews` and, if there are any, it shows all review records on `albums#edit` regardless of who the author/owner of a given record is.

How can I limit the `reviews` returned to only be for the `current_user` and still have their nested form fields built out correctly?

I've tried creating a scope but since I'm calling

```
@albums.reviews.build
```

That doesn't work. I instead made a quick method that pulls all reviews associated with an `album` and does a check to see if the ID of `user` passed to the method matches the review's `user_id` field, but then Rails complains about not being able to call build on an array.

I also tried:

```
@album.reviews.where(user_id: current_user.id).build
```

But nothing appears at all then, even on albums that I've reviewed.

This seems like something that should be easy to do, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure it out.

Comment: Actually, I think @album.reviews.where(user_id: current_user.id).build might be working. I was on an album that had no reviews when I checked it (it was a double-release and I was on the one I hadn't yet reviews). I need to test further, but this could be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was approaching this the wrong way. As I'm already using a hidden field to set the user ID, I put a simple if statement around the nested form fields:

```
<% if f.object.user_id == current_user.id || f.object.user_id.nil? %>
```

And now I only see MY reviews when editing the album, am able to successfully create a new one and then see that one as well when I go to edit the album again.

Thanks for your help @ryan-k!

Answer (score 1):

Your field assignment is in the wrong place. Try something like this:

```
@album.reviews.build(user_id: current_user.id)
```

You'll still need to put the `user_id` in your `permit` statement when you actually submit the form, but that should get you going.

Edit:

Ok, so I think I know what went wrong. You also need to create a hidden field:

```
<%= nested_form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

That way, `user_id` will be passed in with the `params`. You'll still need to put `user_id` in your `permit` statement.

Comment: Annoyingly, it turns out neither this solution or my attempt above to use @album.reviews.where(user_id: current_user.id).build work. I can still all reviews with either line of code, regardless of some being for other users. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Try my edit. If it doesn't work, let me know how it isn't working.

Comment: I already have a hidden field on the nested form fields: <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: (f.object.user_id || current_user.id) %>

Comment: So basically, when the review is saved, the `user_id` field isn't being saved correctly? Can you update your question with the `params` that is submitted to the server? Also your strong params method.

Comment: The form is saving the correct user. That's not the issue and never has been. I just want it to only show associated reviews for an album by the current user or none if the current user hasn't reviewed that album. If I'm looking at, for example, "Nirvana: Nevermind" and haven't written a review for it, on the #edit action, the nested form for Pete's review of it should not be showing for me. It is. When going to albums#edit, any and all reviews show in the nested fields regardless of who the author is. They should be limited only to the author who wrote them.

Comment: Maybe I just need to setup basic rules with CanCan or something.

Comment: Ok, I see. What is your `fields_for` line look like? That is going to be the key line in this case.

Comment: `<% unless @album.new_record? %>
          <%= f.fields_for :reviews do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'review_fields', f: builder %>
          <% end %>
          <p><%= link_to_add_fields "[+] Add review", f, :reviews %></p>
        <% end %>`

Comment: I don't get it...I wrote this method on album.rb:

Comment: `def user_reviews(user)
    self.reviews.where(user_id: user.id)
  end`

Comment: And changed the call in #edit to: `@album.user_reviews(current_user).build` but it still shows mine and Pete's review. In the console, when I run that function passing in my user object and get the count, it shows 1. So the method is working, but for some reason, the nested form is showing ALL reviews no matter what. I guess it must have to do with the f.fields_for but I have no idea how to modify that for it to work how I want it to.

Comment: I just tried this for the nested fields: `<%= f.fields_for :reviews, @album.reviews.build(:user_id => current_user.id) do |builder| %>` and it only shows the empty form now, no existing reviews at all. Same result with my `user_reviews` method.